# `rails server puma` vs. `puma`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

Some guides ([example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby#change-procfile)) recommend this to start one's webserver

```
bundle exec rails server puma
```

But I've always just started the server with `puma` directly

```
bundle exec puma
```

Does something special happening when firing up puma (or any other server) via `rails server`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use `rails s <server>`, the server is launched from the Rails command and is aware of the Rails environment.

This makes possible, for example, to use any of the features and flags offered by the `rails server command`.

```
rails s --help
Usage: rails server [mongrel, thin, etc] [options]
    -p, --port=port                  Runs Rails on the specified port.
                                     Default: 3000
    -b, --binding=ip                 Binds Rails to the specified ip.
                                     Default: 0.0.0.0
    -c, --config=file                Use custom rackup configuration file
    -d, --daemon                     Make server run as a Daemon.
    -u, --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the server.
    -e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this server under (test/development/production).
                                     Default: development
    -P, --pid=pid                    Specifies the PID file.
                                     Default: tmp/pids/server.pid

    -h, --help                       Show this help message.
```

For instance, you can attach a debugger to the session passing `--debugger` or daemonize the server.

The second advantage is that you can version the `Puma` instance, since you will have to list the gem in the `Gemfile`. This is already true if you start it with `bundle exec` like you are doing.

Conversely, when you simply run `$ puma` (or `$ bundle exec puma`) you're not passing through the Rails system. `Puma` will try to find a rack bootstrap file and will use it (it works because Rails provides a `config.ru` script in the application root.

Generally speaking, there is no real difference if you don't need to pass specific options to the server. I like puma and I tend to use it in some projects even when on production we use Unicorn, thus running `$ puma` as a standalone command is handy because I don't need to add it to the `Gemfile`.

However, I would probably go with `$ rails s puma` if my entire stack uses `Puma`. This is also the [command suggested in the documentation](https://github.com/puma/puma#rails).

Comment: when running rails s puma the config file you have does not get loaded... that is the downside. Here is a quick alias to starting up the sever with a config file (config/puma.rb). JUST COPY PASTE echo 'alias start_puma="bundle exec puma -p 3000 -S ~/puma -C config/puma.rb"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile THEN USE start_puma

Comment: The recommended command on the linked page is now `bundle exec puma` (7 December 2018).

Comment: It's not clear what is recommended from that page. But from what I can gather, `puma` has a separate notion of environment which is used to select a configuration file. And `bin/rails s` picks up this environment automatically (from `RAILS_ENV`).

Comment: ...or possibly not a separate notion of environment. Maybe it just doesn't consider itself `rails`-only web server, and therefore can't rely on `RAILS_ENV` variable. After all, it respects `RACK_ENV`.