# Why is Puma only binding to tcp6? (via `rails s`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipv6, puma

Brand new generated Rails 4.2.0 project.  Ran `rails s`, behaved as expected using WEBrick:

```
vagrant@web1:~$ netstat -nlpt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27158/ruby2.1   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                :::*                    LISTEN      27158/ruby2.1
```

Added puma to Gemfile, ran bundle, then `rails s` again; came up with Puma, but only bound tcp6 interface, not tcp:

```
vagrant@web1:~$ netstat -nlpt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                :::*                    LISTEN      27116/ruby2.1
```

Any clue why?  I've been googling with no luck.

**UPDATE:**

Running `puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:3000` works.  However, adding the bind directive to config/puma.rb and running `rails s` doesn't:

```
bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'
```

The threads/workers directives in my config file are working, however, so I know the config file is getting loaded and used.  (Even added a puts statement to be sure.)

The config file even gets picked up if I just run `puma`, binding to the correct interface.  I may just have to resort to running `puma` instead of `rails s`, even though it's annoying and has to be added to my developer docs.

**UPDATE2:**

I was mistaken.  Running `rails s` does not pick up config/puma.rb automatically.  Still investigating...

Comment: This is no longer an issue for me because I've decided to use `puma` to run the rails app instead of `rails s`, which makes everything work -- though I still think this problem should be fixed. The reason I have to switch to `puma` is so the config file gets picked up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225444/how-to-run-rails-puma-server-with-config-file-using-rails-s-puma

Comment: Another solution, if using this behind an apache/nginx reverse proxy is just to use the IPv6 address.

Comment: `bundle exec puma`

Answer (score 3):

The problem you see is that Puma by default binds to `localhost`. This was treated as a normal hostname by the underlying Rails TcpServer and there resolved to only one IP address (the IPv6 version in your case) but not to both the IPv4 and IPv6 versions.

This issue has been dealt with in [Puma issue #782](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782) and [solved](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782#issuecomment-233448657) on July 18, 2016 with [this patch](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782#issuecomment-190815414). In current versions, an exception is made specifically for `localhost`, which now binds to both the IPv4 and IPv6 resolutions.

For all other domains, Puma will still bind to the *first* IP address returned by the system's name resolution. In these cases, you can at least choose if you want Puma to bind to the IPv4 or IPv6 resolution by adding an appropriate entry to `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

Running rails like:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

works for me. The problem is that "localhost" (the default bind address)  bind on IPv4 and IPv6 and the v6 is chosen if both are available.
`0.0.0.0` force the use an IPv4 address (also work with `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: For me, even after running this command rails listens on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: @MichaelGabay But that's as expected. It solves OP's problem that running `rails s` listens only on `tcp://::1:3000` (means localhost but only using IPv6 protocol).