# Why Puma rails server only accepts localhost:3000 rather than 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

Trying out Puma as my Rails server.

Anybody know why the Puma rails server only accepts localhost:3000 rather than 127.0.0.1:3000?

I'm going to want to test Facebook OAuth, and that will need an IP address.

Comment: Same question / duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768479

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000`?  That's always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `env PORT=port_number rails s -b your_IP_Address`
And the server will start on `https://your_IP_Address:port_number`

Comment: perfect! works on rails 7 too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was [Puma issue #782](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782) and was [solved](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782#issuecomment-233448657) on July 18, 2016 with [this patch](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782#issuecomment-190815414).

**Details:** The problem you see is that Puma by default binds to `localhost`, which was treated as a normal hostname by the underlying Rails TcpServer and there resolved to only one IP address (the IPv6 version in your case) but not to both the IPv4 and IPv6 versions. Due to this, it was not accepting connections on `127.0.0.1:3000` as you saw. In current versions however, an exception is made specifically for `localhost`, which now binds to both the IPv4 and IPv6 resolutions.